# Links will not stay inside of the navigation bar

Tags: css, navbar

The links are going out of the navigation bar, because it is too tall (I think), and I want the items to go aside from eachother.

```
#navbar {
    height: 21px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Oh and here's the HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
          {block:AskEnabled}
          <div class="navitem"><a href="/ask">{AskLabel}</a></div class>
          {/block:AskEnabled}
          {block:SubmissionsEnabled}
          <div class="navitem"><a href="/submit">{SubmitLabel}</a></div class>
          {/block:SubmissionsEnabled}
           <div class="navitem"><a href="{text:Link 1 Path}">{text:Link 1}</a></div class><div class="navitem"><a href="{text:Link 2 Path}">{text:Link 2}</a></div class><div class="navitem"><a href="{text:Link 3 Path}">{text:Link 3}</a></div class>


          </div id="navbar">
```

Ignore the stuff in brackets like AskLabel, and the div class navitem, I got rid of it :P

Comment: what links? Can we see your HTML?

Comment: Oops :P I added the HTML

Comment: the  </div id="navbar"> is just  </div>

Comment: That still didn't work :P

Comment: is this live website? Can you post a link

Comment: By "because it is too tall" do you mean it is too thin? When you say "out of the navigation bar" do you mean the links start inside, but don't fit all the way, or that the links are simply not at all inside?

Comment: Here's a link: http://derektheme5.tumblr.com/

Comment: You want the links to be next to one another? Don't wrap each in a div. Use a span tag instead.

Comment: Also `</div class>` should just be `</div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your links are in `div`s, which are block elements, there is a page break between each `div`. You need to use something like a `span` or set `display: inline` on your `navitem` `div` elements.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/7dPkQ/3/

Edit for clarification: `span`s by default have `display: inline` set. `div`s by default have `display: block` set. In your example, the links will go side by side if they are wrapped in an `inline` element. See also http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: I added display inline, but it's still in a list.

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle example to the answer.